# Date Stamp into a String

Tags: iphone, date, datestamp

I'm sure this is a easy problem, but I just can not seem to find how to do this anywhere.  I need to use the current Date and save it into a String.  I do not know how to get the dat stamp.
Could someone please help me out?
Thank you for your time!
-Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set your format according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateFormatter, [heres a link with examples](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)